# sharepoint 2007 login/logout statistics

Tags: sharepoint, authentication, tracking, logout

I want to track my employee in/out time within sharepoint. Here is what i want to do

Employee will singin on Sharepoint when they in and logout (could be singin evening once again) when they leaving.

I want to capture their login and logout timing on sharepoint context using some simple method. I read audit loging section but it contains more info.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as SharePoint sessions are really stateless this will be difficult to track, especially on multi server farms. E.g. What do you consider a log-off event, what if the user just closes the browser?

[I actually implemented this in a commercial product](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2011/02/sharepoint-audit-suite-20-sharepoint.html) that builds on top of the Audit log to determine when users have logged-on or off. It works really well, but it may be overkill for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps SharePoint Usage tracking keep that kind of information?

If not, maybe a custom HttpHandler could be of use.

Comment: yes,... as i mentioned Audit report provide these info in excel format with extra data.  I'm looking some easiest way to look only login/logout time.

Comment: Do you want to display it to the user on a page or something else? As you stated the audit reports contains the info you want, how do you mean "track"?

Comment: basically i would like to have these info on sharepoint web page.  USERNAME    -   LOGIN TIME    - LOGOUT TIME